# Can't make sublimeText gitgutter plugin running on live

Tags: git, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I installed the GitGutter pluggin in sublimeText2 via Sublime Package Control.

Then, when I open a file which is in a git repository (there is a `.git` file in the same directory), and modify it (add new line etc.), nothing appears on the gutter (even after saving the changes).

I tried to manually run gitgutter, by typing cmd+shift+P and `GitGutter: compare against HEAD` and then it shows me the changes on the gutter! But hence, when I do other changes, I always have to run manually `Compare against HEAD` to display the changes, it does not work in live...

I checked my sublime-setting files, and "live_mode" is `true`.

Does anybody have an idea of how I could get it work ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like other people have experienced the same problem: see https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/issues/245 (although the issue title says Windows, there is a comment from someone on a mac confirming that it also affects them).  As the issue is currently open, and there are no workarounds listed, it looks like there is no known solution yet, but it would probably be your best bet to subscribe for notifications on the thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to an issue with GitGutter not finding the git executable.

From the [README](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/blob/1f673cbe009e2e0f4393c25e83be895871b4923f/README.md):

### It's not working!?

The most common reason for the icons to not show up is likely a problem with GitGutter finding the `git` executable on your [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Please read the section on the [git_binary](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter#git-path) setting for how to fix that.

#### Git path

If `git` is not found but GitGutter you may need to set the `git_binary` setting to the location of the git binary, e.g. in a portable environment;
`javascript
"git_binary": "E:\\Portable\\git\\bin\\git.exe"`

Or in a POSIX environment you can run `which git` to find the path to git if it is in your path.

Comment: Is that Sublime setting or package setting?